Can the RESTful API of Microsoft Identity for bearer tokens be scaffolded in .NET 8?
I created a project in Visual Studio using Microsoft Identity, but only the API with bearer token authentication, without any UI. I want to modify the default endpoints that come with it. Because of this, I thought scaffolding the endpoints might be the solution I need, but I haven't found any way to do this.

webapi is back-end which doesn't have ui. Are you looking for MVC with Azzure EntraId Authentication?

Yes, it's a backend Web API. No, I'm not looking for MVC with Azure. What I want is to customize the default Identity bearer token Web API provided by Microsoft. I already scaffolded the UI following the documentation provided by Microsoft, but it didn't affect the endpoints.
